# is there a prescribed way for a chrome app to find the ~/ folder on the file system?

Tags: filesystems, google-chrome-app

I'm writing a chrome app that (ideally) would find the user's Dropbox directory located under their home directory `~/`.

As an (irrelevant) reference, Macromedia's Flash has a methodology for requesting that directory from the Runtime so that you don't have to go looking for it yourself.

I don't see anything comparable in the `chrome.fileSystem` class and am wondering what the "best practice" approach is to finding that directory? Or if I just have to brute force it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chrome.fileSystem` is supposed to access locations that the user selects. You cannot just "probe" for folders without presenting a selection dialog.

Just ask the user to select the Dropbox folder.